# how do i use alexa's data.alexa.com url

Tags: web-services, amazon-web-services, web, alexa-skills-kit

i want to read the country of any website from Alexa's Data from XML

so i tried

http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&url=http://www.flipkart.com

but this just returns the following for all domains

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<ALEXA VER="0.9" URL="alexa.com/" HOME="0" AID="=">
<RLS TITLE="Related Links" PREFIX="http://" more="0">
<RL HREF="www.alexa.com/blocker?tag=pfcp2YmYvjxYjfxUj=0000000000000&ref=data.alexa.com/" TITLE="Please click here to continue using Alexa"/>
</RLS>
</ALEXA>
```

is there another way to axes alexa data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sign up with Amazon Web Information Service at https://aws.amazon.com/awis/